# Query across child and parent node

Tags: aem, jcr

I have a structure like this 
`

```
/content/mysite/contacts/johnsmith/jcr:content/contact,
/content/mysite/contacts/john2dave/jcr:content/contact,
/content/mysite/contacts/adamwashingto/jcr:content/contact,
/content/mysite/contacts/janesmith/jcr:content/contact`
```

...etc, in
`/content/mysite/<nameofuser>/jcr:content`, there is a property called "pagename",each one has a different value. and in 
`/content/mysite/<nameofuser>/jcr:content/contact`, there is a property called "firstname", of course, each "firstname" has his own name.

Now I want to find all the 'contact' nodes whose "firstname"='john' and those parent nodes jcr:content has a pagename="abc".
How do I write this query in JCR SQL2?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way of achieving it would be using [JOINS](http://docs.jboss.org/jbossdna/0.7/manuals/reference/html/jcr-query-and-search.html#jcr-sql2-joins) and the [ISCHILDNODE](http://docs.jboss.org/jbossdna/0.7/manuals/reference/html/jcr-query-and-search.html#d0e7872) join conditions of the JCR SQL2

Assuming your `jcr:content` is of type `cq:PageContent` and `contact` is of type `nt:unstructured`, the query would be

```
SELECT * FROM [cq:PageContent] as parent 
    INNER JOIN [nt:unstructured] as child 
    ON ISCHILDNODE(child, parent) 
    WHERE ISDESCENDANTNODE(parent, '/content/mysite') 
        AND child.firstname = 'john' 
        AND parent.pagename ='abc'
```

You can also refer to this [JCR Query Cheat Sheet](https://wiki.magnolia-cms.com/display/WIKI/JCR+Query+Cheat+Sheet) for quick reference.